# Using python serial connection to communicate with Roboclaw motorcontroller

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

So im newish to python and im trying to use the following program to control a roboclaw motor controller.  I have one motor i am just trying to turn via serial commands and am failing miserably.  Everything works well with pwm using an arduino but when i run it via raspi over serial in python...it just turns slow and always in the same direction. Roboclaw specifies that full fwd motion achieved by sending 127, 64 is stop, and 1 is full reverse.  Electrically its connected appropriately and the motorcontroller is set to the right setting and baudrate, but something with this code is no good...just turns slow and only in one direction and never stops with the stop command.  Help an old man out and let me know what you think.  The code is as follows:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import serial

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyS0',
    baudrate  = 38400,
    parity =serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1)

#allstop = 0b00000000 or 0 
#fwd  = 0b00000001 or 1
#stop = 0b01000000 or 64
#rev  = 0b01111111 or 127

ser.write('00000001')
time.sleep(5)
ser.write('01000000')
time.sleep(5)
ser.write('01111111')
time.sleep(5)
ser.write('00000000')
print 'done'
```